# Query en DB2 con group by & having count: veces que se repite un teléfono en un listado excluyendo repeticiones en personas repetidas

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, db2, base-de-datos

Es una query que a priori parece sencilla, seguro que alguien que domine lo saca rápido, pero me está costando mucho y no encuentro la manera...

Imaginad una tabla RECIBOS que tiene: NOMBRE, TELEFONO, NIF, EDAD, FECHA.

Imaginad también que es una tabla de recibos, y que cada uno es una fila. Por lo que pueden existir NIF's repetidos con distinta fecha. Por ejemplo:

Juan,   650101010, 11111111A, 23, 02/06/2020

Juan,   650101010, 11111111A, 23, 07/06/2020

Juan,   664333333, 11111111A, 23, 08/06/2020

Carlos, 650101010, 22222222B, 26, 02/06/2020

Carlos, 650101010, 22222222B, 26, 08/06/2020

Carlos, 650101010, 22222222B, 26, 09/06/2020

Silvia, 650101010, 33333333C, 30, 03/06/2020

David,  666252525, 44444444D, 35, 04/06/2020

Sara,   650101010, 55555555E, 33, 07/06/2020

Necesito controlar qué personas distintas han utilizado más de 3 veces el mismo número de teléfono. Y he de sacar en la select el teléfono que se repite y el número de veces que se ha repetido. Además, en los casos que la persona y el teléfono sean el mismo, cuentan como un solo caso, no suman.

En resumen:

1. Cuyo teléfono se repita más de 3 veces
2. Si el teléfono y el NIF se repite N veces, cuenta como una sólo

En el caso el ejemplo, el teléfono 650101010 se repite 7 veces (condición 1):

Juan,   650101010, 11111111A, 23, 02/06/2020

Juan,   650101010, 11111111A, 23, 07/06/2020

Carlos, 650101010, 22222222B, 26, 02/06/2020

Carlos, 650101010, 22222222B, 26, 08/06/2020

Carlos, 650101010, 22222222B, 26, 09/06/2020

Silvia, 650101010, 33333333C, 30, 03/06/2020

Sara,   650101010, 55555555E, 33, 07/06/2020

pero los casos de Juan y Carlos están repetidos, por lo que para que se cumpla la condición 2, debería quedar en:

Juan,   650101010, 11111111A, 23, 02/06/2020

Carlos, 650101010, 22222222B, 26, 02/06/2020

Silvia, 650101010, 33333333C, 30, 03/06/2020

Sara,   650101010, 55555555E, 33, 07/06/2020

Mi query tendrá que sacar: "650101010, 4"

Además, la edad no puede ser mayor de 60, y he de contar a partir del 01/01/2020. En el ejemplo no hay casos así, pero he de tener en cuenta esas condiciones en la query.

He logrado hacer hasta la condición 1 con esta query:

**select TELEFONO, count(TELEFONO)
from RECIBOS
where EDAD>60 and FECHA > '01/01/2020'
group by TELEFONO having count (TELEFONO)>3
order by count(TELEFONO) desc;**

Ésto me está sacando los teléfonos que aparecen más de 3 veces, pero los casos repetidos cuentan, por lo que sale: "650101010, 7"

No sé cómo aplicar también la condición 2 hacer para que las personas repetidas no cuenten. He probado de hacer un distinct del NIF, pero me obliga a meter el NIF en el group by, y ya me saldría entonces agrupado por NIF y teléfono, en dos grupos que tendría que sumar y ver si pasan de 3. No me sirve por tanto. Necesito que me salga "650101010, 4". Lógicamente, la BD es mucho más grande, lo he simplificado para el ejemplo.

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo? Cómo poder contar las veces que se repite el teléfono pero haciendo que las personas repetidas cuenten como 1 vez sólo.

Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: En "RECIBOS" prueba sea un subquery donde devuelvas SELECT DISTINCT NOMBRE, TELEFONO, NIF FROM RECIBDOS WHERE  EDAD>60 and FECHA > '01/01/2020' (las condiciones que indicas). Lo demas de GROUP BY .... dejalo como esta.

Comment: Merci, pero no funcionaría. Al hacer en IN de esa subselect vuelvo a consultar RECIBOS, por lo que otra vez saldrían los duplicados. Las subselects sirven si eliminan resultados distintos que no encuentre el IN, pero no para repeticiones. Al menos como lo he probado yo.

Comment: select TELEFONO, count(TELEFONO) from (subquery) group by TELEFONO having count (TELEFONO)>3 order by count(TELEFONO) desc;

Comment: En DB2 no funciona el from (subquery). Me temo que ese es el problema. Pero la solución veo que podría ser una tabla temporal: WITH Temporal AS(...) select Temporal...